# Choose n random elements from every row of list of list

Tags: python-3.x, random

I have a list of list `L` as :

```
       [
         [1,2,3,4,5,6], 
         [10,20,30,40,50,60],
         [11,12,113,4,15,6],
        ]
```

Inner list are of same size.
I want to choose n-random elements from every row of `L` and output it as same list of list.

I tried the following code:

```
import random
import math

len_f=len(L)
index=[i for i in range(len_f)]
RANDOM_INDEX=random.sample(index, 5))
```

I am stuck at this point that how can I use random index to get output from L.

The output for "2" random elements would be:

```
       [
         [1,6], 
         [10,60],
         [11,6],
        ]
```

If random  function chose 1 and 6 as index.

Comment: Are you OK with duplicates in your selections?

Comment: In successive iteration duplicates is fine. But suppose I chose n=2 then I don't want duplicates.

Comment: If no duplicate is desired, consider `random.sample()`; otherwise, consider `random.choices()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`random.sample` could be leveraged. Adapt sample size `k` according to your needs.

```
In:  import random   
In:  [random.sample(ls, k=3) for ls in L]
Out: [[1, 2, 6], [60, 10, 30], [4, 12, 15]]
```

It assumes the order of the picked elements doesn't matter.

Doc for `random.sample` for convenience: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample