# randomly choose N elements from each row of 2d array in python

Tags: python, performance, numpy-random

I have a 2d array, say, `a = [ [1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6,7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], ...[21, 22, 23, 24] ]`, and I would like to pick `N` elements from each row *randomly*, based on a probability distribution `p` which can be different for each row.

So basically, I'd like to do something like `[ np.random.choice(a[i], N, p=p_arr[i]) for i in range(a.shape[0]) ]` **without** using a loop, where `p_arr` is a 2d array the same shape as `a`. `p_arr` stores the probability distribution for each row in `a`.

The reason I want to avoid using a for loop is because running a line profiler shows that the loop is slowing down my code by a lot (I have large arrays to work with).

Is there a more python-ic way of doing this?

I checked out these links ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51021544/select-random-non-zero-elements-from-each-row-of-a-2d-numpy-array) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58783205/choose-n-random-elements-from-every-row-of-list-of-list)) but they don't answer my question.

Thank you!

An example of what I'd like to do without the loop:

`a = np.ones([500, 500])`

`>>> p_arr = np.identity(a.shape[0])`

`>>> for i in range(a.shape[0]):`

`...     a[i] = a[i]*np.arange(a.shape[0])`

`...`

`>>> [print(np.random.choice(a[i], p =p_arr[i])) for i in range(a.shape[0])]`

Comment: So `p_arr ` is 2D? Can you share a minimal example?

Comment: Is there a reason for using `a[i]` and `i in range(a.shape[0])`, instead of just doing `np.random.choice(x) for x in a)` ?

Comment: @yatu yes, p_arr is a 2d array. I've added an example. thanks!

Comment: @match, you're right, I can do it the way you suggested, but I still won't be avoiding the for loop, which is my main concern.

Comment: It's not really a loop - you're just looking at each item in a once. I'm not sure you can get any more efficient than that without looking at running in parallel?

Comment: @match so you're suggesting it'll be faster than ```a[i]``` and ```for i in range(a.shape[0])``` ?

Comment: It should be quicker since it doesn't need to work out the shape of a, or call range - it can just operate on `a` directly. However in either case there's still only one pass over `a` - so while its a `for` 'loop' there's no actual looping.

Comment: @match that's really helpful, it was a subtle point I never realized! thanks a lot, it did help speed up the code quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps using a list comprehension instead of a loop would address the issue:

```
import numpy as np

shape = (10,10)
N     = 4
distributions = np.random.rand(*shape)
distributions = distributions/(np.sum(distributions,axis=1)[:,None])
values        = np.arange(shape[0]*shape[1]).reshape(shape)

sample        = np.array([np.random.choice(v,N,p=r) for v,r in zip(values,distributions)])
```

output:

```
print(np.round(distributions,2))
[[0.03 0.22 0.1  0.09 0.2  0.1  0.11 0.05 0.08 0.01]
 [0.04 0.12 0.13 0.03 0.16 0.22 0.16 0.05 0.   0.09]
 [0.15 0.04 0.08 0.07 0.17 0.13 0.01 0.15 0.1  0.1 ]
 [0.06 0.13 0.16 0.03 0.17 0.09 0.08 0.11 0.05 0.12]
 [0.07 0.08 0.09 0.08 0.13 0.18 0.12 0.13 0.07 0.07]
 [0.1  0.04 0.11 0.06 0.04 0.16 0.18 0.15 0.01 0.15]
 [0.06 0.09 0.17 0.08 0.14 0.15 0.09 0.01 0.06 0.15]
 [0.03 0.1  0.11 0.07 0.14 0.14 0.15 0.1  0.04 0.11]
 [0.05 0.1  0.18 0.1  0.03 0.18 0.12 0.05 0.05 0.13]
 [0.13 0.1  0.08 0.11 0.06 0.14 0.11 0.   0.14 0.14]]

print(sample)
[[ 6  4  8  5]
 [16 19 15 10]
 [25 20 24 23]
 [37 34 30 31]
 [41 44 46 45]
 [59 55 53 57]
 [64 63 65 61]
 [79 75 76 77]
 [85 81 83 88]
 [99 96 93 90]]
```

If you want non-repeating samples on each line, there is another kind of optimization that you could try.  By flattening the values and the distributions, you can create a non-repeating shuffle of indexes of the whole matrix according to the respective distributions of each line.  With the flattened distributions, each group of values that belong to the same line will have (as a group) an equivalent distribution.  This means that, if you reassemble the shuffled indexes on their original lines but keeping their stable shuffled ordered, you can then take a slice of the shuffle matrix to obtain your sample:

```
flatDist    = distributions.reshape((distributions.size,))
flatDist    = flatDist/np.sum(flatDist)
randomIdx   = np.random.choice(np.arange(values.size),flatDist.size,replace=False,p=flatDist)
shuffleIdx  = np.array([randomIdx//shape[1],randomIdx%shape[1]])
shuffleIdx  = shuffleIdx[:,np.argsort(shuffleIdx[0,:],kind="stable")]
sample      = values[tuple(shuffleIdx)].reshape(shape)[:,:N]
```

output:

```
print(sample)
[[ 3  7  2  5]
 [13 12 14 16]
 [27 23 25 29]
 [37 31 33 36]
 [47 45 48 49]
 [59 50 52 54]
 [62 61 60 66]
 [72 78 70 77]
 [87 82 83 86]
 [92 98 95 93]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be used instead of using the loop.

```
a = np.ones([500, 500])
p_arr = np.identity(a.shape[0])
a2 = a.flatten()
a3 = a2*np.full(shape=a.shape, fill_value=np.arange(a.shape[0])).flatten()
p_arr3 = p_arr.flatten()/a.shape[1]
print(np.random.choice(a3, a.shape[1], p =p_arr3))
```

I had to use `np.array.flatten()` multiple times to convert the 2D array into 1D array. Then we can avoid using the loop by performing our operations on the 1D array.

Comment: `flatten()` is still performing a loop internally to return the flattened data - this is just moving the problem, and adding an extra step of creating a flat object which may be less performant/memory-efficient.